# Не могу понять почему не работает блок else в условии

Tags: python, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(lambda message: re.match(r'^8\d{10}$', message.text.strip()), state=UserState.waiting_for_contact)
async def process_contact(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    contact = message.contact
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    username = message.from_user.username
    phone_number = message.text.strip()
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['phone_number'] = phone_number
        first_name = None
        last_name = None
        if contact is not None and 'first_name' in contact:
            first_name = contact['first_name']
        data['first_name'] = first_name
        data['last_name'] = last_name
        data['username'] = username
        cursor.execute('SELECT phone_number FROM users WHERE phone_number = ?', (phone_number,))
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        if result is not None:
            pass
    if re.match(r'^8\d{10}$', phone_number):
            await bot.send_message(user_id, "Заявка почти заполнена, 
осталось отправить скрин ")
            save_user_data(user_id, data)
            await UserState.waiting_for_screenshot.set()
    else:
        print("Некорректный номер")  # Добавьте это для отладки
        await bot.send_message(user_id, "Некорректный номер. Пожалуйста, 
введите номер, начинающийся с '8' и содержащий 11 цифр.")
        await UserState.waiting_for_contact.set()
```

Вот полная функция, в которой мы должны получить номер юзера, но блок else не работает. Не могу понять почему, ведь в if все доходит.
В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Вы наверное, не целиком вставили код.

Comment: Прошу прощения, заменил

Comment: Советую, кстати, познакомится с такой вещью, как отладчик) Обычно подобные проблемы он решает на ура.